# SSL Errors on Python packages

Tags: python, ssl, configuration, pip, failed-installation

I am a programming novice, and I'm trying to learn Python. When I attempt to install packages on Windows 10 (example: pip install -U XXX) I keep getting the following error:

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/XXX/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement XXX (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for XXX

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I've gathered that the problem is related to my internet configuration, but so far I've been unable to find any specific instructions on how to fix this. Again, I'm a beginner, so please no advanced jargon. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is something to do with the installation or setup. Besides, a new version of pip came out a couple of days ago and you should probably upgrade. Try getting the get-pip.py script from [this page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and follow the instructions to run it. Then try using the new pip (9.0) to get your XXX package above.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure the problem is with my version of pip per se. When I attempt the update I get C:\>python -m pip install -U pip
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

`pip` has a `--cert` flag that you can pass the CA bundle you're using i.e if you're using custom ssl certificates.

```
pip install <package-name> --cert <path-to.pem-cert-file>
```

If you have the SSL cert with you but it's a `.cer` file, worry not. Use the following command to convert it into a `.pem` file

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```